# gensim.scripts "No such file or directory"

Tags: python, cmd, gensim

I am trying to analyze Wikipedia dump file. I am using gensim.scripts, a Python library, and running this command in Windows 10 cmd.exe:

```
python -m gensim.scripts.make_wiki enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2 wiki_en_output
```

This gives me the error:Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

```
2015-12-03 15:47:20,459 : INFO : running C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gensim-0.12.3-py2.7-win32.egg\gensim\scripts\make_wiki.py enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2 wiki_en_output
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gensim-0.12.3-py2.7-win32.egg\gensim\scripts\make_wiki.py", line 84, in <module>
    wiki = WikiCorpus(inp, lemmatize=lemmatize) # takes about 9h on a macbook pro, for 3.5m articles (june 2011)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gensim-0.12.3-py2.7-win32.egg\gensim\corpora\wikicorpus.py", line 270, in __init__
    self.dictionary = Dictionary(self.get_texts())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gensim-0.12.3-py2.7-win32.egg\gensim\corpora\dictionary.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.add_documents(documents, prune_at=prune_at)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gensim-0.12.3-py2.7-win32.egg\gensim\corpora\dictionary.py", line 119, in add_documents
    for docno, document in enumerate(documents):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gensim-0.12.3-py2.7-win32.egg\gensim\corpora\wikicorpus.py", line 290, in get_texts
    texts = ((text, self.lemmatize, title, pageid) for title, text, pageid in extract_pages(bz2.BZ2File(self.fname), self.filter_namespaces))
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2'
```

Thoughts on what I should do to fix this?

On Windows 10. gensim.scripts has been installed.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the whole path to the downloaded enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2, or try to run gensim script from the download folder.

If you haven't that archive - you may find and download it from dumps wikimedia website